# How to pass variable json string into application or session variable using c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, html, session

```html
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        SELECT bank name
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        father name
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        father pan no
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        mother name
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        mother pan no
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        Account numbers
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="fno"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="button" runat="server" value="Generate Ffile" id="file" onclick="submit_file_Click();" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
var accountNum;
var bank_name;
var bank;
var fn;
var fpan;
var mn;
var mpan;
var jsonObj = [];
var customerString;
var accString;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#file").on("click", function() {
    customerdetails(amc_name);
    accountDetails();
  });

});

function customerdetails(amc_name) {
  jsonObj = [];
  bank = bank_name;
  fn = $("#fname").val();;
  fpan = $("#pan1").val();;
  mn = $("#mname").val();;
  mpan = $("#mpan2").val();;

  item = {}
  item["BANKName"] = bank;
  item["F_Name"] = fn;
  item["F_PAN"] = fpan;
  item["M_Name"] = mn;
  item["M_PAN"] = mpan;

  jsonObj.push(item);
  customerString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
}

function accountDetails() {
  jsonObj = [];
  accountNum = $('textarea#fno').val();

  item = {}
  item["ACNum"] = accountNum;
  jsonObj.push(item);
  accString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
}
```

when user enter details onto html form than I used jQuery to get JSON String of customer details and account details .Now I want to store these JSON  string into application or session variable where customer details will  store into one session variable and account details will store into another session variable.
I am using but is not working

Comment: What are you using? Classic .NET or .NET Core

Comment: using C#  .NET Framework 4 and using normal html web form and jQuery

Comment: Thanks @MAdeelKhalid .I STORED INTO HIDDEN FIELD .Now how can I user on serverside?

Comment: Put an `asp:button` and within `OnClick` event handler, verify whether your `hiddenfield` has the value or not.

Comment: @Ziel, please enter all the nodes to the question itself, it isn't worth for every1 to look through the comments.

Comment: thanks @MAdeelKhalid Its working

Comment: That's good. I'm removing the comment and posting it as an aswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not do this because `serverside` code executes before the `javascript`. You can do this by using `hiddenfield`, set `hiddenfield` value from `jquery` and get that from your `serverside`.